# Matlab: Track point on object in video

Tags: matlab, video, tracking

I would like to track (if that is the right word for this) the movement of a point on an object and return the co-ordinates for the point in each frame to arrays for plotting. How would you go about doing this?

The point on the video is a certain color and so my first effort was to eliminate all other colors and change the part I wish to follow to black and everything else to white. Doing this left me with some areas in the background which are the same color but I wish to ignore them and just focus on the moving point. I do not know where to even begin with this or if I've even been trying to do the right thing so far?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for terms like 'tracking', 'morphological', 'computer vision', 'matlab'

Here's a project that I found that will probably get you started.
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28757-tracking-red-color-objects-using-matlab

Answer (score 0):

if your object of interests is of a certain specific color.  You can always apply a color-filter.  To give you a bit of a background, i was trying to track not a point on an object, but a moving object in one of the videos i have.  (it was a ping-pong video and my goal was to track the ping-pong ball).  My algorithm was simple and fast (as i did not want any of my filters to induce heavy computations at one single frame).  The basic idea was to apply a color filter.    Similar to other shape filters, if your target is of high similarity to the filter, the response will be distinctive enough for you to notice.   In other words, if you minus two objects that are extremely similar, you will get 0, otherwise, it will be far greater than 0.

Comment: Hey, thankyou for the help before. I have been using a color filter and everything seemed to be going fine, however I have found that this has led to a few problems due to lighting issues, causing the object of interest to change color because of reflections. Can you suggest any other tracking methods? Is it possible to track the object by its shape? And if so could you point me in the right direction of where to start?